# systemd-journal-remote claims that the logfile is corrupt

Tags: systemd-journald

I am trying to upload my journald logs from a server to a centralized server. I am using systemd-journal-remote and systemd-journal-upload for this.
The initial sync of existing logs goes perfectly. After a while, when uploading new logs, systemd-journal-remote starts claiming that the log is corrupt.

```
# journalctl -u systemd-journal-remote
Dec 07 11:59:41 syslog systemd-journal-remote[1459]: /var/log/journal/remote//remote-192.168.100.85.journal: Journal header limits reached or header out-of-date, rotating
Dec 07 11:59:44 syslog systemd-journal-remote[1459]: /var/log/journal/remote//remote-192.168.100.85.journal: Journal header limits reached or header out-of-date, rotating
Dec 07 13:25:55 syslog systemd-journal-remote[1459]: File /var/log/journal/remote//remote-192.168.100.85.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
Dec 07 14:14:04 syslog systemd-journal-remote[1459]: File /var/log/journal/remote//remote-192.168.100.85.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
Dec 07 22:06:10 syslog systemd-journal-remote[1459]: File /var/log/journal/remote//remote-192.168.100.85.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
Dec 08 07:14:29 syslog systemd-journal-remote[1459]: File /var/log/journal/remote//remote-192.168.100.85.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
```

It moves the current file to a journal~ file.

```
# ls -l /var/log/journal/remote
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote   8388608 Dec  8 09:08 remote-192.168.100.85.journal
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote  83886080 Dec  7 13:25 remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef3c05a61f38-d9e2719124309c81.journal~
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote   8388608 Dec  7 14:14 remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef3cb1d4ed0a-4409c128d6c7996f.journal~
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote   8388608 Dec  7 22:06 remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef434a3c6e81-cd917ee1470654d7.journal~
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote   8388608 Dec  8 07:14 remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef4af3270982-8d69c39c835093b4.journal~
-rw-r----- 1 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote  75497472 Dec  7 11:59 remote-192.168.100.85@20cd77d5c97e47119c33de6c4ca2c0d2-0000000000000001-0005c3d7d8a4d2a4.journal
```

The strange part, is that these files are perfectly readable by journalctl, and verify returns PASS.

```
# journalctl --file="/var/log/journal/remote/*.journal~" --verify
PASS: /var/log/journal/remote/remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef4af3270982-8d69c39c835093b4.journal~                                                            
PASS: /var/log/journal/remote/remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef3c05a61f38-d9e2719124309c81.journal~                                                            
PASS: /var/log/journal/remote/remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef434a3c6e81-cd917ee1470654d7.journal~                                                            
PASS: /var/log/journal/remote/remote-192.168.100.85@0005ef3cb1d4ed0a-4409c128d6c7996f.journal~
```

Nothing is logged on the systemd-journal-upload server.

Both source and destination servers are running Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal) server with systemd version 245.
I have tried using both http and https as transport. I also tried to upgrade the systemd-journal-remote server to Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) (systemd 249). All resulting in the same behaviour.

Why is it doing this? This is filling up my diskspace, as the journal~ files are always at least 8MB, but sometimes only contain 2 log lines.